# How to do SystemVerilog-style bit vector slice assignment in C++?

Tags: c++, bitset, system-verilog

I am porting some SystemVerilog code to SystemC/C++. I am using std::bitset to represent bit vectors, but I can see already it falls short of providing methods to access a slice.

For example, if I want to set reg1 to bits 4-8 of reg2 with the SystemVerilog code:

```
bit [3:0] reg1;
bit [15:0] reg2;
reg1 = reg2[7:4];
```

How could I do this with std::bitset?

```
bitset<4> reg1;
bitset<16> reg2;
reg1[0] = reg2[4];
reg1[1] = reg2[5];
reg1[2] = reg2[6];
reg1[3] = reg2[7];
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I would write a function `subbit(const std::bitset<N>& bits, size_t begin, size_t end)` that masks out the bits you want, shifts them to the right so `begin` is at bit 0, etc., then return that value. Where it goes is up to you.

Comment: Note there is a fundamental dissonance here: the range could be specified at run-time but the bitset size is specified at compile-time. Unless you guarantee the range is denoted by integral-constant expressions, you can't say for sure (without a run-time check) the resulting range is small enough to fit in the destination bitset. That is, you have to check at runtime that `end - begin <= N`. You could provide an alternate function `subbit_c<B, E>(std::bitset<N>) -> std::bitset<E - B>` to ensure matching types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you are using SystemC, why don't you use sc_bv<> to represent HDL signals natively? Because SystemC has a set of data type to represent HDL bit/logic-wise and word logical operators, it should be more easy to mapping SystemVerilog/Verilog data types to C/C++ code.

```
sc_bv<4> reg1;
sc_bv<16> reg2;
reg1 = reg2.range(7,4);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about sc_bv, I will check it out.

Comment: Yes so far this is doing just what I want. Also it supports both constant and variable ranges.

Answer (score 4):

If your want to operate on bitsets - then use to_string function:

```
bitset<4> reg1;
bitset<16> reg2;
reg1 = bitset<4>(reg2.to_string().substr(4,4));
```

This is not very efficient way, but should work.

If you do not have bitsets bigger than 32 or 64 bits - then use version with `to_ulong` or `to_ullong` - it should be more efficient.

Also consider to use `std::vector<bool>` instead of `std::bitset<>`. Folks here have tendency to make downvote every time they see `std::vector<bool>`, but it could be more efficient here:

```
vector<bool> reg1(4);
vector<bool> reg2(16);
reg1.assign(reg2.begin() + 4, reg2.begin() + 8);
```